# Check if current point is on route (path) and get those points from list where it matches

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

Next function `com.google.maps.android.PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath` only returns boolean value to tell if checked point (location) is on path

```
PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng, mPointsOfRoute, true, 10);
```

(https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.java#L158)

But I also would like to find out where this point was matched, between which points from my point list (`mPointsOfRoute`)

Because I need to short this route (path), remove points which were passed and make shorter route from new current position to the same destination

Comment: You could just iterate through mPointsOfRoute and call isLocationOnPath() for every n and n+1 pair of coordinates. For example, in the first iteration you check mPointsOfRoute.get(0) and mPointsOfRoute.get(1). For the next iteration you check mPointsOfRoute.get(1) and mPointsOfRoute.get(2), etc...

Comment: @GavinWright yes I've already done something like this. Also as I understand in this case I can set `false` instead of `true` as third parameter of `isLocationOnPath` function which is `geodesic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose p is the Polyline and you found out that:

`PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(latLng, mPointsOfRoute, true, 10);`

returns true, where:

`List<LatLng> mPointsOfRoute = p.getPoints();`

So, the latLng is somewhere on p.

You can use the `findIntersectingPoint()` method to find the LatLong of the intersecting location.

Just pass the List of LatLngs to this method, like this:

`LatLng intersectingLocationOnPath = findIntersectingPoint(latLng, mPointsOfRoute.get(0), mPointsOfRoute.get(mPointsOfRoute.size() - 1));`

```
private LatLng findIntersectingPoint(final LatLng p, final LatLng start, final LatLng end) {
    if (start.equals(end)) {
        return start;
    }

    final double s0lat = Math.toRadians(p.latitude);
    final double s0lng = Math.toRadians(p.longitude);
    final double s1lat = Math.toRadians(start.latitude);
    final double s1lng = Math.toRadians(start.longitude);
    final double s2lat = Math.toRadians(end.latitude);
    final double s2lng = Math.toRadians(end.longitude);

    double s2s1lat = s2lat - s1lat;
    double s2s1lng = s2lng - s1lng;
    final double u = ((s0lat - s1lat) * s2s1lat + (s0lng - s1lng) * s2s1lng)
            / (s2s1lat * s2s1lat + s2s1lng * s2s1lng);
    if (u <= 0) {
        return start;
    }
    if (u >= 1) {
        return end;
    }

    return new LatLng(start.latitude + (u * (end.latitude - start.latitude)),
            start.longitude + (u * (end.longitude - start.longitude)));
}
```

Comment: I guess it would be better first iterate through all points `mPointsOfRoute` and call `isLocationOnPath()` for every `n` and `n+1` and if it returned `true` then call `findIntersectingPoint` between those points (pair). And you have to remove passed points. Though I'm not sure how perfect `findIntersectingPoint` method works, it finds Intersecting point but it's not that accurate though. So we can't really call like this `findIntersectingPoint(latLng, mPointsOfRoute.get(0), mPointsOfRoute.get(mPointsOfRoute.size() - 1));`, for first and last point

Comment: seems `findIntersectingPoint` works ok if point isn't that far from other two point of line

Comment: I'm going to do it in different way, iterate though all points, but I will use your function `findIntersectingPoint` too, thanks for it, it's very useful

Comment: Ok. Great. Thanks.